# Excel VBA - If value exists > x, add to sum

Tags: vba, excel

I have a table with time values.  If any value exists in a specified row that is greater than 90 minutes (1:30:00), I need to add the difference (i.e. how much greater it is) to a running total at the end of the row.  So, that box could be blank, could have just one cell's value, or could have multiple values added.  I already have the For loop to go through each cell in a row.  I need the part to sum the values.  And ideally, if there was a nested loop to do 6 separate sums for the 6 rows...

```
'Add break munutes
fp.Activate
Dim rng As Range
For Each rng In Range("B3:F3")
    If rng.Value > TimeValue("1:31:00") Then

    End If
Next rng
```

[image]

Comment: BTW, VB uses `#` for date and time literals: `If rng.Value > #1:30# Then` or `If rng.Value2 > 0.0625 Then`

Comment: why do you not just do a sumif?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hard to say if this is fully accurate without more information, but something like this should work for you:

```
Sub tgr()

    Dim aTimes As Variant
    Dim dTime As Double
    Dim aSumResults() As Double
    Dim lResultIndex As Long
    Dim i As Long, j As Long
    Dim bFirst As Boolean

    dTime = TimeValue("01:00:00")
    aTimes = ActiveSheet.Range("B3:F9").Value 'Change to the full table range
    ReDim aSumResults(1 To UBound(aTimes, 1) - LBound(aTimes, 1) + 1, 1 To 1)

    For i = LBound(aTimes, 1) To UBound(aTimes, 1)
        'Each i represents a row of the data
        'Go through each column and collect the conditional sums
        lResultIndex = lResultIndex + 1
        bFirst = True   'Use bFirst to ignore first value greater than dTime
        For j = LBound(aTimes, 2) To UBound(aTimes, 2)
            If aTimes(i, j) > dTime Then
                If bFirst Then
                    'This if the first value found for the row, ignore it
                    bFirst = False
                Else
                    'Not the first value found, include in sum
                    aSumResults(lResultIndex, 1) = aSumResults(lResultIndex, 1) + aTimes(i, j) - dTime
                End If
            End If
        Next j
    Next i

    'Output the results
    ActiveSheet.Range("G3").Resize(UBound(aSumResults, 1)).Value = aSumResults

End Sub
```

Comment: I think this could work, however I made the mistake in typing B3:B9, when it should be rows, B3:F3, B4:F4, ect.  I apologize for that.

Comment: so I adjusted the code for a timevalue of 1 hour, since none of the days had a value above an hour and 30.  However, the output for each row was odd.  In the range of -0.01 to -0.001 for each row that had values over 60 minutes.  Any ideas?  For example, row 3 gave -0.0302546296296296

Comment: @sbagnato Did you change the TimeValue in both locations?  It's in the code twice.

Comment: if I could facepalm on here, I would.  That line was slightly off my screen so I did not see it.  Now it works great.  If you want me to ask this in a new question, I can.  However, do you think there is anyway to get it to ignore the first instance of over 90 minutes, but then add subsequent instances?

Comment: @sbagnato Updated code.  It will ignore the first instance over `dTime` (which is a variable I added so you only have to change the desired time in a single location) for each row.

Comment: Awesome!  Thanks!

Comment: Hey @tigeravatar how can I edit this code so that if the value is larger than a threshold, count it anyway?  For instance, if the analyst goes above 95 minutes on break, the first value is counted anyway.  I have not changed your code above much besides changing variable names.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to avoid VBA, this can actually be done by an Excel formula:

```
=SUMIF($B$3:$B$9,">"&1.5/24)-COUNTIF($B$3:$B$9,">"&1.5/24)*1.5/24
```

That sums up all values that exceed 90 minutes, and then subtracts off 90 minutes from the total for each value that has been counted.

[image]

Comment: Yes, that does work.  However, I need to do it in VBA.  As noted above, I had a typo, the times are in a row (B3:F3), not a column, my apologies.

Answer (score 2):

I would recommend Excel Formula if that is an option, because of the restrictions of VBA solutions.

```
=SUMPRODUCT((B$3:B9-1/16)*(B$3:B9>1/16))
```

or a bit shorter with array formula (enter with Ctrl + Shift + Enter) :

```
=SUMIF(B$3:B9-1/16,">0")
```

Answer (score 1):

You said you wanted the sum of the times in a row but then defined B3:B9, so I assumed you meant the sum of the times in a column.
Try this:

```
Dim i As Integer
Dim num1 As Date
For i = 3 To 9
    If Cells(i, 2).Value > TimeValue("1:30:00") Then
        num1 = Cells(10, 2).Value + Cells(i, 2).Value - TimeValue("1:30:00")
        Cells(10, 2).Value = num1
    End If
Next i
```

I've defined where the sum is put as cell B10. You could make a similar loop for each column. I tried this out and it worked for me.

Comment: Yes, I apologize.  I meant row, but typed out a column.  So the first row would be B3:F3, the second C4:F4, and the final one B9:F9.  The sums of the values over 91 minutes would go in G3, G4....G9.